# PostgreSQL Case statement based on other values in same Group

Tags: postgresql, group-by, case, psql

I have the following table and want to write a `SELECT` (in PostgreSQL) that will produce the table below it. It should `GROUP` by `timestamp` and where there's an 'X' and a 'Y' with the same `timestamp`, it should be classed as 'Standard', otherwise 'Premium' if there are only 'X's in the same timestamp.

```
|         timestamp       | data |
|--------------------------------|
| 2018-08-13 09:26:10.872 |  X   |
| 2018-08-13 09:26:10.872 |  Y   |
| 2018-08-13 09:26:11.125 |  X   |
| 2018-08-13 09:26:11.125 |  X   |

|        timestamp        |   type   |
|-------------------------|----------|
| 2018-08-13 09:26:10.872 | Standard |
| 2018-08-13 09:26:11.125 | Premium  |
```

I have gotten as far as writing the following:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp,
    CASE
        WHEN -- ??
        THEN 'Standard'
        ELSE 'Premium'
    END AS type
FROM my_table
GROUP BY timestamp, type;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to group by `timestamp` only, and to count the distinct `data` entries. To get a boolean value out of this count (required by the `case when`), you would compare it to 1:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp,
    CASE
        WHEN count(distinct data) > 1
        THEN 'Standard'
        ELSE 'Premium'
    END AS type
FROM my_table
GROUP BY timestamp;
```

Comment: Thank you, that does answer the question I asked.